# Does Black night support ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, java, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I've created a c# desktop application in visual studio and a web application using ASP.NET MVC4. The data from the desktop application is the source for the web application. Does anyone know if black night supports ASP.NET MVC 4? Or does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: What is "black night"?

Comment: It's a hosting site https://www.blacknight.com/